# Proper way to make the expiration of the FormAuthentication Cookie redirect to login

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, forms-authentication

I am using Form

Web.Config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Login/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

within the LogOn Method:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, isPersistanceCookie);
```

My understanding is that when the cookie is deleted, it could automatically redirect to the login page (calling the LogOn method), but this does not work.

Within Global.asax.cs, within the

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
....
....
....
        if (!currentPage.Contains("login"))
        {
            HttpCookie loginCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            if (loginCookie == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("/login");
            }
        }
 }
```

I don't believe this is the right way to approach it as it seems very prone to security flaws.

Any help is much appreciated!